# Exercises with solutions for mathematical statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, soft-question

I'm currently studying the statistics part of the book *Georgii: Stochastics*, contents are [here](https://www.degruyter.com/view/supplement/9783110293609_Contents.pdf) (chapters 7 - 12). Sadly, there are no solutions for the exercises given in this book.

Do you know a similar textbook or another source where I can get exercises **with solutions** for mathematical (inferential) statistics? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I find solutions useful, but only if I have the stick-to-it-ness to seriously try to solve each of the exercises before looking at the solution.  A few years back I solved and worte up in LaTeX all the problems in Munkries and at least for the first 5 chapters it was a fun experience.  That said, most bookes won't contain solutions because it is felt that people won't spend the time solving the exercises themselves and then the exercises become worthless. Perhaps a good compromise is the annoying "solutions to odd numbered problems" approach.

Comment: @MarkFischler: I have to know if my solutions are correct. I could post the solutions here, but "solution-verification" questions are not so well received (ok, still better than at physics.SE). Also if I post my solutions here the exercises become worthless for others by that logic.